# Вопрос по объединению DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть dataframe

| ID | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Совпадение | Название1 | Цена1 |
| 21cd1231dw | czxca21 | 1324512 |
| Совпадение | Название2 | Цена2 |
| Совпадение | Название3 | Цена3 |

Надо по нему пробежаться и если совпадает id добавляем дубль справа в столбцы с названием name_1 и price_1

если совпадений несколько то добавляем name_2 , name_55 и тд

пробовал поиграться с объединением dataframe
merge:

```
df_merged = df.merge(df, on='ID')
```

Дубли не удаляет
на выходе получается

| ID | Name | Price | NAme_x | Price_x" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Совпадение | Название1 | цена 1 | Название2 | Цена2 |
| Совпадение | Название1 | цена 1 | Название 3 | Цена3 |
| 3123asdas | asdased2 | 12315125 |  |  |

Если использую

```
df_merged = df.join(df, rsuffix='_right')
```

просто находит строку и справа делает ее дубль

Короче все варианты перепробовал и более или мене что работает это .merge и то дубли оставляет.

Объясните пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Получается даже не так, просто он находит строку и копирует ее справа за исключением ID. А нужно чтобы все id объединились в одну строку.

На выходе я хочу получить

| ID | Name | Price | NAme_x | Price_x" | Name_y | Price_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Совпадение1 | Название1 | цена 1 | Название2 | Цена2 | Название3 | Цена3 |
| Совпадение2 | ыфввыф | 15251423 | фывфыв | 12331 |  |  |
| Совпадение3 | asdased2 | 12315125 |  |  |  |  |

т.е 1 строка формируется из всех строк с значением id = Совпадение1, а справа пишем значения Name и Price тех строк где id совпало и тд

Comment: результат конечный какой должен быть? вы не представили. на каждое совпадение 2 новых столбца? а если совпадение по id и по одному из следующих столбцов или по всем трем, нужны при этом новые столбцы?

Comment: ну у меня на данный момент он пробегает по строкам и сопоставляет справа два дубля
.т.е 
```
ID                          Name        Price     Name_x     Price_x
Совпадение1    Название1  Цена1  Название1   Цена1


и тд

а я бы хотел чтобы получился результат , где все строки проверяются на совпадения столбца ID  а Name и PRice перемещаются справа от первого совпадения

т.е так:

ID                          Name        Price     Name_x     Price_x    Name_y     Price_y
Совпадение1    Название1  Цена1  Название2   Цена2   Название3  Цена3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так попробовать.

Допустим у нас есть такой ***df***

```
>>> df
   id name  price
0   1    a    100
1   1    b    200
2   1    c    300
3   2    d    400
4   2    e    500
5   2    f    600
6   3    g    700
7   3    h    800
8   1    j    900
```

Тогда.

***Вариант 1***:

```
new_df = df.assign(k=df.groupby(['id']).cumcount()).set_index(['id', 'k']).unstack()
```

Переименуем столбцы

```
new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x, y in new_df.columns]
```

Отсортируем, чтобы столбцы были в нужном вам порядке и сбросим индекс

```
new_df = new_df.reindex(sorted(new_df.columns, key=lambda x: x[-1]), axis=1).reset_index()
```

Получаем:

```
>>> new_df

   id name_0  price_0 name_1  price_1 name_2  price_2 name_3  price_3
0   1      a    100.0      b    200.0      c    300.0      j    900.0
1   2      d    400.0      e    500.0      f    600.0    NaN      NaN
2   3      g    700.0      h    800.0    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
```

***Вариант 2*** *(Вроде проще)*:

Без группировке в данном случае все равно никуда, поэтому

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg(name=('name', lambda x: x.to_list()), price=('price', lambda x: x.to_list())).reset_index()
```

Далее создадим функцию, которая принимает на вход ваш датафрейм и название столбца и возвращает новый датафрейм.

```
def return_col(your_df, col: str):
    list_of = your_df[col].to_list()
    max_len_of = max([len(i) for i in list_of])
    df_of = pd.DataFrame(list_of, columns=[f'{col}_{i}' for i in range(max_len_of)]).fillna(np.nan)
    return df_of
```

пример:

```
>>> print(return_col(df, 'name'))
  name_0 name_1 name_2 name_3
0      a      b      c      j
1      d      e      f    NaN
2      g      h    NaN    NaN
```

с помощью данной функции создадим несколько новых df для начальных столбцов

```
name = return_col(df, 'name')
price = return_col(df, 'price')
```

соединим их и отсортируем

```
df_np = pd.concat([name, price], axis=1)
df_np = df_np[sorted(df_np, key=lambda x: x[-1])]
```

и добавим наш id

```
df_last = pd.concat([df['id'], df_np], axis=1)
```

получим

```
>>> df_last

   id name_0  price_0 name_1  price_1 name_2  price_2 name_3  price_3
0   1      a      100      b      200      c    300.0      j    900.0
1   2      d      400      e      500      f    600.0    NaN      NaN
2   3      g      700      h      800    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
```

***p.s.*** На мой взгляд первый вариант надежнее

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Все работает шикарно, правда думал это как то попроще организуется. А не подскажите что за столбец Unnamed: 0_1 появляется  ?

Comment: т.к. вы не предоставили своих данных, я делал на своих и в них не появляется столбца unnamed. можете скинуть свои данные (хотя бы 10 строк) ссылкой на файл и можно будет посмотреть

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fp9z5NLriix3sfUjXkoefw0Jbb3MbITLii0qt1W2z8c/edit#gid=703756419

result_new это входные данные
Vrode_vse это результат действий описанных вами выше

Comment: @IvanShmidt с вашими данными по первому варианту тоже все в порядке получается. Вы точно ничего в коде не меняли?) это первое и второе - старайтесь использовать названия не на русском)

Comment: Ничего не изменял, только входные данные на русском. Ну это не критично, мой вопрос решен. Еще раз благодарю

Comment: А не подскажите, как сделать так чтобы сортировка не слетала если повторений больше 10?